# Leakage Inductance Delays the Secondary Current

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I read [Basso's seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf), on Page 30, it is talking about Leakage Inductance Delays the Secondary Current. From the formula, we can get the Δt, but I am curious about one thing if we don't add the RCD clamp circuit in flyback (which mean we don't have Vclamp in the equation), how do I calculate the Δt. Any formula could replace it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Calling @VerbalKint

Comment: Hi @Verbal Kint. 

Did you know that?

Comment: I'm here : ) The time \$\Delta t\$, which is the leakage inductance reset time, depends on the clamp voltage and the reflected level which set the reset slope expressed in \$S_{leak}\$ (first line of the second slide). From there, you can calculate \$\Delta t\$ with the line below. In these expressions, you have references to the clamp voltage and hence the \$RCD\$ network selection.

Comment: Hi @Verbal Kint,

From your book, I know The time Δt, which is the leakage inductance reset time, but this is based on the Vclamp.

I am curious about if I don't add any clamp circuit in flyback, can I know the  Δt? in this situation I don't know the exact reset voltage on leakage inductance. that's why I ask.

Comment: I see, the clamp will certainly be the MOSFET body diode which avalanches at the switch turn-off and it is not recommended.

Comment: Hi @VerbalKint,

So do you mean we usually don't do that? 
It seems we can't calculate the Δt without clamp circuit, am I correct?

Comment: Reset occurs as soon as the clamp exceeds the reflected output. So if you don't have a clamp, then the reset voltage - provided you have a HV MOSFET - will peak to \$I_p\sqrt{\frac{l_l}{C_{lump}}}-\frac{V_{out}}{N}\$ (see slide 26 of my seminar) and reset will also be ensured but in a less efficient way since what you want it truly to reset quickly.

Comment: HI @VerbalKint,

 I see, thanks.